# How to find and update inner items in embedded models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to change some of inner items. What is the best way to do that?

```
const country=mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{...},
    name:{...},
    states:[{
        _id:{...},
         state_name:{...},
         cities:[{
         _id:{....},
         city_name:{...}
         }]
    }]

})
```

```
for example:

{
  _id:10,
  name:country_10,
  states:[{
    _id:20,
    state_name:state_20,
    cities:[
      {
         _id:30,
         city_name:city_30
      },
      {
         _id:40,
         city_name:CHANGE THIS
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Want to update second city by _id

Is it better to use three models instead of this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of scenario purely using mongo [**$[] positional operator**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in conjucture with filter on **city id** & `arrayFilters` can work:

Although consider three models and sperating them out is a viable option as well.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "states.cities._id": 40 },
  { $set: { "states.$[].cities.$[elem].city_name": "IAM_CHANGED" } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": { $eq: 40 } }]
  }
);
```

**Which outputs:**

```
{
  _id: 10,
  name: "country_10",
  states: [
    {
      _id: 20,
      state_name: "state_20",
      cities: [
        {
          _id: 30,
          city_name: "city_30"
        },
        {
          _id: 40,
          city_name: "IAM_CHANGED"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Replace that **db.collection** with the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
CountryModel.findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $set: { "states.0.cities.1.city_name": "Dublin" } })
```

`$set` works with a path to the field you want to change. The `0` and `1` are the index in the arrays.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set

Edit:

I think this should work if you only know the ids:

```
CountryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: 10, "states._id": 20, "states.cities.city_name": 40 }, 
  { $set: { "states.$.cities.$.city_name": "Dublin" } },
)
```

Comment: thanks. but what if I only know the "_id" and nothing more. How can I get access to index?